# Why generate simple HTML via PHP heredoc?

Tags: php, html, heredoc

I have inherited a website for which I need to make some changes.  As always there are many ways to do things in website development.  However, this particular site has me confused.  All the html is delivered via heredoc php scripts.  However, none do any php processing.

For example (structure only) index.php:

```
<?php
$html = <<<html

<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        {more simple HTML here.  No php processing to be done}
    </body>
</html>
html;
echo $html;
?>
```

I understand the php but I can't figure out why they generate the page this way as oppose to simply deliver it without the php variable processing. Before I just assume the person had no idea what they were doing I thought I'd ask.  Any ideas?

This is my first post to StackOverflow so feedback on forum etiquette also welcome.

Comment: Here is heredoc details, might be useful to you :http://in3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: Usualy people tend to do this with xml documents that they play with before saving into an actual file... now it seems to me that the coder that built the page didn't like the *lazy server* ideal.

Comment: As far as SO etiquette goes, just have a read through the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Your question is well-written and clear, which is a great start!

Comment: I found out the person was using a code generating GUI to create the site.   I don't think he edited any of the files directly.  The heredoc format is simply how the program generates code.  Thanks so much for the quick feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be because they intended to use PHP variables within the HEREDOC. Your example doesn't have those, but I would hazard a guess that they are used in places. From there, I would then just imagine HEREDOC used everywhere for consistency.

Comment: This turns out to be correct.  The files were generated by a website building program.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the heredocs is probably because you don't have to escape quotes or worry about quotes at all within a heredoc, whereas string literals you have to manage the quotes accordingly.

It is more common though to keep HTML in a separate file or use a template system - generally that would be a better option than heredocs or string literals.

Comment: I think they're wondering: why store the HTML into a variable then echo it?  Wouldn't it be better to escape PHP then just include it "naked"?

Comment: @GigaWatt That's exactly what I was wondering.  It seemed odd to use heredoc formatting for pure html.   However, I found out the php files were generated by another program used to create the site.  This is the default output method for the generator.

Answer (score 1):

PHP files are already template files in HTML.

Replace your code with:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        {more simple HTML here.  No php processing to be done}
    </body>
</html>
```

Just having HTML in the body of a PHP file, outside of `<?php` and `?>`, returns the HTML.

Comment: I agree.  I'm going to change the code to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You could spend weeks trying to get into the head of a legacy developer and it is just wasted time.

I would suggest refactoring the code to just not need anything in PHP in those instances, there is no benefit to doing what they have done and it is going to be a jarring experience for you each time you go into edit it.

Comment: This is what I'm going to do. Besides having no benefits, my editor parses the code as PHP instead of HTML.  Which for me is a pain.